# Can 300dpi screens be captured in XCode?

Tags: ios, xcode, screenshot

Does anyone know if it's possible to capture screens from my app in 300 DPI? I'd like to build a script that takes screens for print use.

Answer (score 0):

Run the (Retina) simulator(s), CMD + S to save the screenshot to desktop. DPI varies between [264 - 400 for newer devices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retina_Display).